# Kann man das Präfix eines trennbaren Verbes als Adjektiv sehen?

Tags: verb, adjective

Ich möchte erklären was ich meine:

Zum Beispiel, bei dem Satz:

> Ich schätze sie hoch.

Wenn man das jetzt noch mehr hervorheben möchte, kann man ein "sehr" vor dem "hoch" stellen, als wäre "hoch" hier bloß ein Adjektiv, d.h.:

> Ich schätze sie **sehr** hoch.

Bzw. in diesem Beispiel mit *auffallen*:

> Er fällt **sehr** auf.

Oder wäre das falsch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Man kann Verben im Satz genau wie ein Adjektiv mit Adverbien oder präpositionalen Bestimmungen erweitern. Ich würde das nicht unbedingt so ausdrücken, dass man das Präfix  als Adjektiv sieht, aber wenn dir diese Vorstellung hilft, kannst du es so sagen, es kommt grammatisch auf das Gleiche heraus.

Eigentlich hängt es aber nicht damit zusammen, ob das Verb ein- oder zweiteilig ist, sondern das kann man mit allen Verben machen.

Dein Beispiel:

> Ich schätze sie sehr hoch.

Das *sehr* erweitert streng genommen eigentlich nicht das *hoch*, sondern das *hochschätzen*, aber es sieht genauso aus, als würde das *hoch* erweitert. Ähnlich ist es in deinem zweiten Beispiel mit *auffallen*.

Bei einem einteiligen Verb:

> Ich mag sie sehr.
> Ich mag sie ganz besonders.